# How do SSL certificate authorities verify domains?

Tags: domains, https, security-certificate

What is a reasonable and reputable SSL certificate signing authority -- **and how do they verify the domain in the simplest case?**  Do they simply send an email to the Technical Contact for the domain name like when initiating a transfer, and then boom, verified certificate?

Answer (score 2):

We have been using [starfieldtech.com](http://starfieldtech.com) for many years now and have found them to be great.

To verify they send an email to the admin contact on the domain record.